# MySQL, rank keywords separated by space

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a table with only one col, and contain free text, and each keyword separated by a space

```
TEXT
apple orange dog
apple banna cat
```

I want to have a result sth like

```
apple 2
orange 1
dog 1
banna 1
cat 1
```

Is it possible with just SQL?

Comment: Will it always be 3 values?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

create Function

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split](@text varchar(8000), @delimiter varchar(20))
RETURNS @Strings TABLE
(   
  position int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  value varchar(8000)  
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @index int
SET @index = -1

WHILE (LEN(@text) > 0)
  BEGIN 
    SET @index = CHARINDEX(@delimiter , @text) 
    IF (@index = 0) AND (LEN(@text) > 0) 
      BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (@text)
          BREAK 
      END 
    IF (@index > 1) 
      BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (LEFT(@text, @index - 1))  
        SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index)) 
      END 
    ELSE
      SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index))
    END
  RETURN
END
```

Query

```
 declare @ColumnNameList VARCHAR(MAX)
select @ColumnNameList  = COALESCE(@ColumnNameList +' ' ,'') +column  from table
select @ColumnNameList 
select value,count(value) as count from (select value from fn_split((select @ColumnNameList),' '))
Space_tbl group by value
```